# Difference between inode numbers of os.stat and os.fstat in python

Tags: python, windows, inode, fstat

I wanted to get file's inode in my windows machine, so first I tried `os.stat('./filename.txt').st_ino`
in my REPL and the output I got was `0L`.

I tried the same for a couple of other files and got the same output.

Then, I tried
`os.fstat(open("filename.txt", "r").fileno()).st_ino` and I got a long integer in output. For different files the integer was getting changed. So, I think os.fstat worked for windows while os.stat did not. Can someone explain to me the reason for this behavior and other differences between both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 on Windows, `stat` calls `GetFileAttributesEx` or `FindFirstFile` to get standard file information, including file attributes (e.g. directory, readonly), size, and timestamps. `fstat` calls `GetFileType` (i.e. character, pipe, disk) and `GetFileInformationByHandle`, which provides the standard info plus the file index number (like an inode in some ways, but not really), number of hard links, and volume serial number (unused).

Python 2 is a year away from end of life. I suggest you upgrade to Python 3, which has an improved `stat` implementation for Windows and further improvements in development